# How can I find the new match position converting an Unicode String to a Byte String?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I know I can convert an UnicodeString to a ByteString and vice versa using these commands:

```
UnicodeStr = ByteStr.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
ByteStr = UnicodeStr.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
```

UTF-8 is multibyte character encoding. 
Characters can have 1 to 4 bytes, the position of a match changes converting from UnicodeStr to ByteStr.
This is not a big problem using english text characters but it is using characters in the French, German, Spanish or Dutch language.

p.e.:
UnicodeStr = "Ça te changera les idées John!"  (=That’ll take your mind off things John!)

The match position of the word "idées" is:

```
p=re.compile("idées")
for m in p.finditer(UnicodeStr):
    print(m.span())
```

--> (19, 24)

How can I find the new match position converting a UnicodeStr  to ByteStr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe by converting the pattern:

```
p=re.compile("idées".encode(encoding='UTF-8'))
for m in p.finditer(ByteStr):
    print(m.span())

(20, 25)
```